# Problems Including GTK for C++ on Manjaro Linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, gtk, manjaro

I've been struggling for hours to include the GTK library for manjaro in C++. I'm using VS Code, I have installed the GTK-4.0 package with the command `sudo pacman -Syu gtk4` and I'm including the file `/usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h` in my C++ program with the line `#include <gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h>`. It's throwing the error

`gtk/css/gtkcss.h: No such file or directory`

even though there is a file named `gtkcss.h` at the path `/usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/css/gtkcss.h`

I've looked all over google and I can't find anyone having the same problem, especially on the same OS. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an include path.

Gtk requires* pkg-config to set the include path. see https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/unstable/gtk-compiling.html

So while you have included it with a complete path, the files inside the library still require the include path to be set.
I don't know which build system you are using, but in general gtk requires something like:

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags) -c main.cpp
```

This will expand to the right flags to set the include path.

*You might also do this manually by adding a `-I` flag. But that is prone to break if you want to compile on a different machine.